# Why am i not able to place Generic Handler file as a root file?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, generic-handler

The problem i am facing is that whenever i add new item and choose Generic Handler file.The "place code in separate file" option is disabled as a result the handler file appears inside other files. I am using visual studio 10.[image]

So when i see the solution explorer the handler file is inside default.aspx file just like default.aspx.cs file.Here is the picture of it.

[image]

See the handler file is inside the Default.aspx file. 

What i want is to have this handler file in the root directory just like test.aspx file as in the picture.

Comment: Sorry, but I really do not understand what is the issue from your comments

Comment: ok let me edit it a bit to make it more clear.

Comment: It is on the root, and they did not need to open anything because you call it as `file.ashx`

Comment: I need generic handler file just like any other .aspx file having its own .ashx.cs file so that i can create object of any .aspx.cs class and use them on .ashx.cs file. Like i can do Default mydef = new Default(); and create a new object of default class inside the ashx file.But with handler file itself inside the Default.aspx,i am not able to create object of Default inside .ashx file.

Answer (score 0):

Generic handlers did not have html code, they are the most simple programming method that asp.net can provide to send back a replay.

This is done only using one file, that contains only c# and there you place your replay to the browser.

Some examples:
[ASP server stats for html pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786125/asp-server-stats-for-html-pages/9786345#9786345)
[file download by calling .ashx page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087040/file-download-by-calling-ashx-page/12087222#12087222)
[HttpContext.Current.Session is null in Ashx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181408/httpcontext-current-session-is-null-in-ashx-file/14181556#14181556)

Comment: I am not getting what you are trying to say.Can't we add generic handler file in asp.net websites as a separate file.I mean the file is offcourse separate but not in the root of project.when we add an .aspx,it is kept separate which can be extended to get its corresponding .aspx.cs file.But this .ASHX file when added is also placed inside .aspx file.